# Help can't import com.google.android.maps

Tags: android

I already tell project use libraries com.google.android.maps in the manifest of project but in my activity it shows errors about importing com.google.android.GeoPoint. and others.

Comment: at the creation of project which avd you have choose?

Answer (score 2):

which target version you are using? use target Google apis 1.6 instead of android. You can the change the target version from project itself.
1.Right click on the project
2. choose Build path--> Configure Build path
3.Window will be opened, choose Android in right corner of the window then change target version in to Google apis.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the short described question, i can assume below:

Yes you have mentioned it inside the AndroidManifest.xml file but have you choosen the library instead of SDK while creating android application. If no, then you just need to select **Google API (Google Inc.)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can mention it on the AndroidManifest.xml but first of all choose google api sdk.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure you have installed Google API

Then set your project's properties in Eclipse to check off the Google APIs version of the SDK.

and Make sure you have include this library in AndroidManifest FIle

```
<uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Answer (score 0):

//in AndroidManifest.xml >>uses-library android:name = "com.google.android.maps"/>

then add maps.jar   search for maps.jar and coppy path in your computer

example:C:\Users\android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-17\libs\maps.jar

then right click on your projects >>Build Path >> Configure Build Path..>>Java Build Path>>Libraries taps >>Add External jars..>>past path:C:\Users\android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-17\libs\maps.jar>>choose maps.jar click ok..ends thank you.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to format your answer for clarity? Thanks!